# Action method not found by kendo ui grid call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller

I'm trying to add new rows into a Kendo UI grid using a the popup editable property. Everything works fine, every added row appears in the grid. The problem is that the Create action method doesn't exist. Firebug says:

```
 A public action method &#39;Create&#39; was not found on controller &#39;test.Controllers.IdeaController&#39;.
```

However, the action method exists in the controller.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,Idea product)
    {
        using (var db = new test_mockEntities1())
        {
            if (product != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Ideas.Add(product);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return Json(new[] { product }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: as suggested by @jesper I updated the question with the action I'm trying to call.

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Idea product)
    {
        using (var db = new migros_mockEntities1())
        {
            if (product != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Ideas.Add(product);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return Json(new[] { product }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));

    }
```

Comment: This problem probably has nothing to do with Kendo UI. Question should probably be tagged with ASP.NET MVC, or whatever server-side tech you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. I wasn't using kendo.aspnetmvc.js which made Kendo UI use GET instead of POST.